# Specifying different scales for the axes

Tags: pgfplots

I am plotting sin(2x) from -pi/4 to pi/4.  I have specified that the axes should have the same scale with `axis equal image`.  It doesn't look like a sinusoidal function.  How do I get the y-axis to be scaled to half the x-axis?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=6in,axis equal image,clip=false,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-0.7854,xmax=0.7854,
    domain=-0.7854:0.7854, samples=201,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-1,ymax=1,
    restrict y to domain=-1:1,
    enlargelimits={abs=1cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]
\addplot[samples=501,domain=-0.7854:0.7854,blue] {sin(deg(2*x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: They _are_ scaled equally to my eye. Comment out the `xtick` line and add `grid=major` to verify for yourself.

Comment: @ Paul Gessler  The height is about 1.25 times half the width. I made a mistake with saying the function that I graphed.  I graphed sin(2x).  I will edit the post.

Comment: @Paul Gessler  How do I specify the scaling for the y-axis to be half that of the x-axis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `unit vector ratio={2 1}` to make the y-axis scaling half of the x-axis scaling. I've removed a number of things, which were not really relevant to your question, to more clearly illustrate the changes.

The ticks and `grid=major` are just inserted for visual verification of the correct scaling.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  axis equal image,
  unit vector ratio={2 1},
  grid=major,
  xtick={-5,-4,...,5},
  ytick={-5,-4,...,5},
]
\addplot {x};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the code, and illustrating the graph that TikZ draws with it.  I guess that `unit vector ratio={2 1}` instructs TikZ to make a unit in the horizontal direction twice as long as a unit in the vertical direction.

Comment: What does `axis equal image` specify regarding the graph and axes?

Comment: According to the manual, `axis equal image` really just sets the keys `unit vector ratio=1 1
1,unit rescale keep size=false`. So we are overriding that `unit vector ratio`, but keeping `unit rescale keep size=false` because presumably you do not want the axis limits enlarge to maintain the overall aspect ratio of the plot.